# invalid value around character 0 in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, jsonparser

I am developing an iOS application where it uses an API to get the user's information. This is the response I am getting back from the server which is a JSON object:

```
    {
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "OK",
        "error": 0,
        "error_messages": []
    },
    "data": {
        "id": 1111,
        "name": "xxxxxxxx",
        "triple_name": "xxxxxxxx",
        "english_name": "xxxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxxxxx",
        "telephone": "xxxxxxxx",
        "username": "xxxxxxxx",
        "id_type": "xxxxxxxx",
        "id_number": "xxxxxxxx",
        "id_expiry_date": null,
        "id_photo": null,
        "gender": "xxxxxxxx",
        "date_of_birth": "xxxxxxxx",
        "h_date_of_birth": null,
        "nationality_id": 0,
        "country_id": 0,
        "city_id": 0,
        "degree_id": null,
        "personal_photo": null,
        "is_government_employee": 0,
        "iban": null,
        "bank_id": null,
        "access_token": "xxxxxxxx",
        "country_name": "xxxxxxxx",
        "city_name": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error in this line of code:

`let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary`

The error is:

> invalid value around character 0

. I have used a JSON validator and it says the JSON is valid. However, i keep getting this error

Comment: Yes, json is valid I think you have created any wrapper class for AlamOFire and in that key "error" having some problem for passing value, Please check that part where you are passing data "status" data

Comment: try changing `options: .allowFragments` to `options: []`

Comment: The error says the JSON is **not** valid. Print the string right before the JSONSerialization line:  `print(String(data:data!, encoding:.utf8)!)`. I guess it's HTML. And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift and `allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a dictionary.

Comment: I ran your code here,  https://repl.it/repls/LumberingCheerfulIntercept , it works, maybe you are messing up with something else.

Comment: @vadian i added the statement you suggested and i got this response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at platform.xxxxx.sa Port 80</address>
</body></html> does this mean i am getting my response as HTML ? event though when i tried it with postman i get JSON object

Comment: As I suspected, it's HTML, actually a 400 Bad Request server error.

Answer (score 0):

try changing NSDictonary to [String:AnyObject]
or to [String:Any]